# Proove that $2^n=o(n!)$ and $n!=o(n^n)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having a little trouble with this proof.  Trying to show that $2^n$ is little $o$ of $n!$ AND $n!$ is little $o$ of $n^n$.  I'm not sure how to do this conceptually so any help would be appreciated.  I'm also trying this without using Stirling's formula.  Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, sorry guys I wrote it wrong, I meant n!=o(n^n) sorry about that

Comment: What did you try? And is this for homework?

Comment: I have updated the title, please see that the changes are correct.

Comment: Thanks for changing the title, I have the first half, not sure how to proceed on the second half.  Its review for a midterm I have in a week btw.  thanks again guys, just trying to understand it firmly

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Look at the ratios $$\frac{2^n}{n!}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{n!}{n^n}\;;$$ how do they behave as $n\to\infty$?

**Added:** For the first one, note that

$$\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac21\cdot\frac22\cdot\frac23\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac2{n-1}\cdot\frac2n\le 2\left(\frac23\right)^{n-2}$$

for $n\ge 2$. For the other one, note that

$$\ln\frac{n!}{n^n}=\ln n!-\ln n^n=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k-n\ln n\le\int_1^{n+1}\ln x\,dx-n\ln n\;,$$

because $\sum_{k=1}^n\ln k$ is a lower Riemann sum for $\int_1^{n+1}\ln x\,dx$. The integration can be done by parts, and you get

$$\int_1^{n+1}\ln x\,dx=\left[x\ln x-x\right]_1^{n+1}=(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\ln\frac{n!}{n^n}&\le(n+1)\ln(n+1)-n(1+\ln n)\\
&=\ln(n+1)^{n+1}-n\ln en\\
&=\ln(n+1)^{n+1}-\ln(en)^n\\
&=\ln\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{e^nn^n}\\
&=\ln\left(\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^n\cdot\frac{n+1}{e^n}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\cdot\frac{n+1}{e^n}\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and therefore

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\cdot\frac{n+1}{e^n}\;.$$

Comment: yes, I can get that far but I need to prove rigorously that their limits are 0 as n grows large.  Im using the fact that the sum of x^n/n! is convergent, meaning that the seqence x^n/n! tends to zero as n increases to infinity.  Im having a bit of trouble with proving that the limit of n!/n^n =0 as n-->inf.

Comment: @user99714: I’ve added something that should help; there are probably easier ways, but this works, and it’s what occurred to me.